# what is the best way to reduce complexity of geometries

Tags: t-sql, geometry, geography

so I'm playing around with the http://www.gadm.org/ dataset;

I want to go from lat & lon to a country and state (or equivalent).

So to simplify the data I'm grouping it up and unioning the geometies; so far so good. the results are great, I can pull back Belgium and it is fine.

I pull back australia and I get victoria because the thing is too damn large.

Now I honestly don't care too much about the level of detail; if lines are w/in 1 km of where they should be I'm ok (as long as shapes are bigger, not smaller)

What is the best approach to reduce the complexity of my geospatial objects so I end up with a quick and simple view of the world?

All data is kept as Geometry data.

Answer (score 7):

As you've tagged the question with "tsql" I'm assuming you're using Sql Server. Thus, you already have an handy function called [Reduce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933814.aspx) which you can apply on the geometry data type to simplify it.

For example (copied from the above link):

```
DECLARE @g geometry;
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 0 1, 1 0, 2 1, 3 0, 4 1)', 0);
SELECT @g.Reduce(.75).ToString();
```

The function receives a tolerance argument with the simplification threshold.

Comment: I want to only remove the holes not use the accuracy of the outside edge.

Comment: Well, I guess you could use a function called "ConvexHull" (also supported on Sql Server). The problem is that the resulting polygon would be convex, probably distorting your original polygon. Anyway, try it: SELECT @g.STConvexHull()

Answer (score 1):

I suppose complexity is determined only by the number of vertices in a shape. There are quite a number of [shape simplifying algorithms](http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBAfl/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK5/NODE195.HTM) to choose from (and maybe some source too).

As a simplistic approach, you can iterate over vertices and reject concave ones if the result does not intoduce an error too large (e.g. in terms of added area), preferably adjoining smaller segments into larger. A more sophisticated approach might break an existing segment to better remove smaller ones.